# Wrapping Material UI's DataGrid GridActionsCellItem in a wrapper component causes a UI bug when showInMenu is set to true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

My MUI DataGrid columns look like this:

```
const columns = [
    { field: "name", type: "string" },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      width: 80,
      getActions: (params) => [
        <GridActionCellWrapper />,
        <GridActionsCellItem
          icon={<DeleteIcon />}
          label="Delete"
          onClick={() => console.log("abascus")}
          showInMenu={true}
        />
      ]
    }
  ];
```

The wrapper for the `GridActionCellItem` (as you see as the first element in the actions array looks like this:

```
const GridActionCellWrapper = () => {
  // In my actual code I am using a custom hook from apollo codegen to pass into the onClick
  // That's the reason why I'm using a wrapper component
  return (
    <GridActionsCellItem
      icon={<DeleteIcon />}
      label="Delete"
      onClick={() => console.log("abascus")}
      showInMenu={true}
    />
  );
};
```

Note both components have `showInMenu` set to true and have all the exact same props, however the table does not render the three dot menu in the table:

[image]

CodeSandBox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-cell-wrapper-bug-js3lye?file=/demo.tsx
Note that when you remove the wrapper component (`GridActionCellWrapper`) from the `getActions` array, the table render the three dot menu just fine. This leads me to believe that me wrapping the `GridActionsCellItem` component is what is causing the problem. If you're wondering why I am wrapping it, it is because the onClick requires a custom hook call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your GridActionCellWrapper with the following code:

```js
const GridActionCellWrapper = ({showInMenu}) => {
  // In my actual code I am using a custom hook from apollo codegen to pass into the onClick
  // That's the reason why I'm using a wrapper component
  return (
    <GridActionsCellItem
      icon={<DeleteIcon />}
      label="Delete"
      onClick={() => console.log("abascus")}
      showInMenu={showInMenu}
    />
  );
};
```

And your columns constant with:

```js
const columns = [
    { field: "name", type: "string" },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      width: 80,
      getActions: (params) => [
        <GridActionCellWrapper showInMenu={true} />,
        <GridActionsCellItem
          icon={<DeleteIcon />}
          label="Delete"
          onClick={() => console.log("abascus")}
          showInMenu={true}
        />
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Brilliant, it worked, thank you! But isn't my way and your way functionally the same thing? In both cases true is being passed into `showInMenu`.  I'm assuming MUI is looking only at the parent component's props?

Comment: The criterion for grouping is that the immediate elements of the array have the "showInMenu" property. In your code this was not true for the GridActionCellWrapper component.